# Django CSRF Cookie not set for Chrome, Safari but not Firefox

Tags: django

I have recently moved to a new computer. My Django project works fine on the old computer. Running the same code on the new one I find that I get "CSRF Verification Failed" when logging in. This gives  message in the log of 'CSRF cookie not set.'. This happens when using Chrome and Safari but it works find with Firefox.

When I inspect they all have the hidden input for `csrfmiddlewaretoken' but when I look at storage in the browser inspector the cookie is only set in Firefox.

I am at a loss as I've changed nothing in the code and it works fine on my old laptop.

Any suggestions would be greatly received.

Comment: Just add the `{% crsf_token %}` in the forms (and as `csrfmiddleware` in the payload of AJAX post requests).

Comment: That is already there. This all works fine on my laptop. No code change to this computer.

Comment: then the *cookie* does not matter, since then it is in the POST as hidden `<input type="hidden">` field.

Comment: Thats what I thought but I'm getting a "CSRF Cookie Not set' Warning in the log and I'm getting a "Forbidden (403)" response from the server. This works fine on a different computer. It also works fine on Firefox. It fails using Chrome and Safari

Comment: Is this using the development server? What are your CSRF settings, specifically regarding the cookie?

Comment: It is using the development server. In my settings I have `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False` and I have this  `MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]`

Comment: when I step through this it appear Django is looking for the token in a cookie `cookie_token = request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME]`  in `CsrfViewMiddleware` - from Firefox this is present but in Safari and Chrome it isn't. Again this is only happening on my new computer not on my old laptop. Guessing some setting in Chrome and Safari but cannot figure out what

Comment: Honestly, you may have just some settings in chrome from another project on that domain. This just happened to me. If you're not using https, make sure these are set ```SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False```
...and clear all local storage and refresh.

Comment: I just encountered the same thing. With cookies disabled in safari, I cannot post to any form, becuase csrf_token cannot be set. But other browsers still work with cookies disabled on the same view! I think Safari is actually doing the right thing here, but I'm not sure how to account for the difference.